# Blank Environments Setting Dialogue Box

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, installation, windows-7

When I right-click inside a clear area of ArcToolbox and select Environments, the Environments Setting dialogue box is blank.

The only items available are the buttons on the bottom to close, etc.

I am running Windows 7, ArcInfo with SP2 installed, MSMXL 4.0 SP3.

I have done a clean uninstall and a reinstall of ArcInfo w/SP2.

I have contaced ESRI Tech Support, but no solution yet.

Answer (score 2):

After you Install **MSXML4** (Windows 7 comes with MSXML4 SP3 with a patch that does not work for ArcGIS) there needs to be some regedit tweaks

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=3144b72b-b4f2-46da-b4b6-c5d7485f2b42

See the End of this ESRI thread which shows this successfully concluded.

http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/19645-Is-there-a-reset-button-for-settings-How-do-I-restore-original-settings

Note:
Before you make any changes to the registry BACK IT UP first.