# Error 000735: Input Dataset or Feature Class: Value is required

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, coordinate-system, arctoolbox, error-000735

I am a true novice when it comes to ArcGIS and computer programs like this one. Am taking a class and cannot get the Project function to work under the tool box.

The path I used was ArcTool box --> Data Management Tools --> Projections and Transformations--> Feature Path --> Project  --> (This gives me a blank box and when I double click on the OK button I get the following message:

```
Error 000735:  Input Dataset or Feature Class:  Value is required
Error 000735:  Output Dataset or Feature Class:  Value is required
Error 000735:  Output Coordinate System: Value is required
```

Can anyone tell me what I can do to remedy this?

Comment: could you please upload the screenshot ?

Comment: Try to put valid resource as input similarly for output also..

Comment: In my answer, I assumed that "blank box" means a blank tool window. That is, no controls are visible. Is that true? Are all tools blank when you open them?

Comment: See also: [Blank Environments Setting Dialogue Box](http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/11163/753) and [Geoprocessing tool GUI windows displaying blank](http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/49026/753)

Answer (score 3):

The [error message](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/00vp/00vp00000017000735.htm) indicates that you have not entered a required parameter.

> **Description**
>
> A parameter required by the tool has not been utilized.
>
> **Solution**
>
> For a tool to execute, at a minimum, all required parameters must have
>   a value provided. For help in determining whether a parameter is
>   required or optional, look under the syntax sections of the tool's
>   help page.

See also the help for the [Project (Data Management)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/0017/00170000007m000000.htm) tool.

Answer (score 2):

When you say "blank box", do you mean that the tool is blank? Here's a [post](http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/43033-Toolbox-tools-are-blank-ARCMap-10) from the ArcGIS forums with some things to try. Text is reproduced below:

---

You may want to try resetting your Esri application data and registry keys. Please follow these steps to do so:

Please note: Renaming the Application data will result in loss of folder connections, SDE connections, and toolbar locations since it rebuilds the template back to the out of the box feel. Also, editing registry entries can cause issues on your computer. Please be careful when making these changes.

```
A) Rename ESRI Application Data folder. 
- Close all ArcCatalog, ArcMap applications. 
- Browse to the following directory: C:\Documents and Settings\<user profile>\Application Data (you may have to turn on hidden files). 
In Windows 7/Vista:
C:\Users\Username\Applications Data\Roaming(you may have to turn on hidden files from the control panel, go to Appearance and Personalization/Folder Options/Show hidden files and folders) 
- Rename ESRI folder to ESRI_OLD. 

B) Rename the ESRI folder in Registry. 
- Start Menu, Run, type "regedit" 
- Expand HKEY_CURRENT_USER folder 
- Expand Software folder within HKEY_CURRENT_USER 
- Rename the ESRI folder to ESRI_OLD
```

The other good thing to check is if someone else in your company can log onto your machine with their username and password and reproduce the problem. If they also have blank tools, there is probably some kind of conflict preventing the tools from working properly. If they can use the tools, then your windows user profile has become corrupt to the install of ArcGIS and a new profile is needed for functionality to return.

(Thanks to Stephanie W. at Esri)

If these steps do not work, you might want to search [ArcGIS forums](http://forums.arcgis.com) using terms like blank or empty tool.

Comment: +1, I didn't catch that this might be the reason for not entering anything on the tool dialog :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are receiving a .mxd from another source, be sure to check that relative paths is checked under Map Document Properties before running a tool.  Not having relative paths selected will cause the system to throw this error.