# Copying ArcSDE datasets and features in Python give ERROR 000732?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.1, enterprise-geodatabase, error-000732

I keep getting a kick back that says this:

> ERROR 000732: Input Features: Dataset 'Database
>   Connections\Wyoming.sde\Supporting_MT_DBO_Geology' does not exist or
>   is not supported Failed to execute (FeatureClassToGeodatabase).

```
# Import modules
import sys, string, os, datetime, arcpy

# Sets the start time
nowstart = datetime.datetime.now()

# Set location of SDE instance - in this case a special SDE connection just for this script
SDEname = r"C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\ESRI\Desktop10.1\ArcCatalog\Wyoming.sde"
SDEnameShort = r"'Database Connections\Wyoming.sde"


# Set up the log file
LogLoc = r"P:\Database_Backups\SDE\BackupLog_"
LgFile = LogLoc + nowstart.strftime("%Y_%m_%d_%H%M") + ".log"
logfile_out = open(LgFile, 'w')
# Write the start time to the log file
logfile_out.write("Backup process started on " + nowstart.strftime("%Y_%m_%d %H:%M") + "\n")

# Deletes temp timestamp
del nowstart

# Add the Conversion and Data Management Toolboxes to the geoprocessor


#Sets work environment to SDEname
arcpy.env.workspace = SDEname

#Sets environment to overwrite
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

# Resets the start time
nowstart = datetime.datetime.now()

# Creates a variable for naming the backup GDB
YearMonthDayTime = nowstart.strftime("%Y_%m_%d_%H%M")

# Variables and parameters for setting up the backup GDB
outgdb = "PetroPAM_Backup_" + YearMonthDayTime + ".gdb"
outpath = r"P:\Database_Backups"
output = outpath + os.sep + outgdb
print output


#Create the backup GDB
arcpy.CreateFileGDB_management(outpath, outgdb)
print "Created BackupGDB"




# Find and export feature classes in datasets to a backup GDB
logfile_out.write("\nCreating Feature Dataset List...\n")
fc = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()

dsList = arcpy.ListDatasets("*", "Feature")
print dsList
print "The Datasets"
for dsGEO in dsList:
    outDS = arcpy.ValidateTableName(dsGEO)
    arcpy.CreateFeatureDataset_management(output, outDS)
    fcListGEO = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses("*","",dsGEO)
    print fcListGEO
    print "Feature Classes in Dataset"
    for fcGEO in fcListGEO:
        print fcGEO
        print SDEnameShort + os.sep + outDS + os.sep + fcGEO
        arcpy.FeatureClassToGeodatabase_conversion(SDEnameShort + os.sep + outDS + os.sep + fcGEO, output + outDS)
```

Any ideas?  I'm using ArcMap 10.1

Comment: Your input into the conversion process is your feature dataset (dsGeo), not a single featureclass (fcGeo). Is this what you intended? Since you're choosing to loop through your feature classes I would think the input to this process would be a featureclass.

Comment: I basically want to copy the data from the sde to a file geodatabase.  Will it matter if the dataset is empty and has no feature classes in it?

Answer (score 1):

The errors you are encountering are a direct result of not inputting the correct number of parameters into the tool you are calling. [Create Feature Dataset](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help../index.html#//0017000000pv000000) requires both **out_dataset_path** and **out_name**.

In addition to this there are some other issues with your code.

The [help documentation for the Feature Class to Geodatabase tool](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001200000021000000) states:

> The inputs can include shapefiles, coverage feature classes, VPF feature classes, or geodatabase feature classes

You are attempting to input a feature dataset. Since you're choosing to loop through your feature classes I would think the input to this process would be a feature class.

Try this modified version of your code where a feature class in used in place of the feature dataset.

```
    dsList = arcpy.ListDatasets()
    print dsList
    for dsGEO in dsList:
        arcpy.CreateFeatureDataset_management(dsGEO, **out_name**)
        fcListGEO = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses(dsGEO)
        for fcGEO in fcListGEO:
            arcpy.FeatureClassToGeodatabase_conversion(fcGeo, **output_geodatabase**)
```

Pending the rest of your code is correct this will loop through each feature class inside of each feature dataset and add it to your geodatabase.

Comment: It says I need to indent the line after the "for dsGEO in dsList".  If there is an empty dataset will that matter?

Comment: I have updated the code to make the indentation more clear. I would suggest testing with just one dataset that you know to contain featureclasses to ensure that the code runs. After that you can test to see what happens when you input an empty feature class. You can avoid this by ensuring that the dataset contains feature classes (e.g. fc count > 0)

Comment: I think that's the exact code I pasted in?

Comment: I tired it on a database that has feature classes below the dataset and it kicks back the same error message.  Do I need to set the environment to the FileGDB?  I don't know why it kicks back a message saying a value is required.

Comment: Ah - you're missing a required input into the tool. The last line should read: arcpy.FeatureClassToGeodatabase_conversion(fcGeo, output_geodatabase), where 'output_geodatabase' is the path to your geodatabase. This question further explains that specific error: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/50656/error-000735-input-dataset-or-feature-class-value-is-required

Comment: The code can't get that far.  It get's hung up on the CreateFeatureDataset_management line.  It can't create the datasets.  I was just thinking am I able to use the Copy_management process and just use the sde file as the input and output to a file GDB I created?

Comment: The Create Feature Dataset tool is also missing an input. It requires at least: arcpy.CreateFeatureDataset_management(out_dataset_path, out_name).

Comment: I have updated the above code to reflect a few other errors in the original posted code.

Comment: I've got it creating the Dataset, but it won't create the feature classes.  I've updated my code to reflect whats going on. All of the print commands in the code relating to the feature classes don't print when the code is run.

Comment: You need to take a look at the help documentation for each tool. Specifically the INPUTS and OUTPUTS for each tool. Right now you have your input parameters all mixed up. Your parameter that is supposed to be an output geodatabase is currently an input feature class...

Comment: I'm basing it off what the python window says in arcmap.  I'll type in the command in the window and look at the side.  Here's what is has for CreateFeatureclass_Managment(.  I'm using the outpath as the GDB I'm copying to and the out_name, the same name from the SDE.


CreateFeatureclass_management(out_path, out_name, {geometry_type}, {template;template...}, {has_m}, {has_z}, {spatial_reference}, {config_keyword}, {spatial_grid_1}, {spatial_grid_2}, {spatial_grid_3})
 Creates an empty feature class in an ArcSDE, file geodatabase, or personal
geodatabase; in a folder it creates a shapefile.

Comment: It should at least have all of the names printed out.  It's not looking inside the datasets for feature classes.

Comment: If you're running the tool using the code you list above you are not using the correct inputs to the tool. As I said, you need to read the help documentation for these tools and check that your code reflects the proper inputs to the tools you are using.

Comment: There isn't an input and an output.  It's an out_path and an out_name.  That's exactly what it says in the ArcMap documentation.  The list above shows that CreateFeatures_Management should be like this...CreateFeatures_Management(out_path, out_name,{geometry_type}, {template;template...}, {has_m}, {has_z}, {spatial_reference}, {config_keyword}, {spatial_grid_1}, {spatial_grid_2}, {spatial_grid_3})

This is exactly from ArcMap documentation.

Comment: Is this the line you are running: arcpy.CreateFeatureDataset_management(output, outfc)? If so, it's incorrect. If not, please update the code to reflect what you are actually trying to run. Copying the documentation doesn't tell us what you are actually trying to run.

Comment: Yes, that's the command I'm running in my code posted above.  What's the correct command?  arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(input, output)?

Comment: When I go down a level to try to read the feature classes this is what the Python Interpreter kicks back for my print commands.  It shows the Dataset, but has the feature classes blank, when there should be three fcs inside of the dataset.

[u'Client_PFS_Technical.DBO.PFS_Technical']
The Datasets
[]
Feature Classes in Dataset